# PAGE_SIZE in embedded linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, kernel

How do I find the size of PAGE_SIZE in bytes being allocated in my module?
I know it is of either 4 kb, 8 kb or 16 kb but like to know exact size in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`sysconf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) libary call.

Using `_SC_PAGESIZE` as argument will return you the page size for your environment.

Alternatively, you can check for `page.h` source code of your kernel, it should also give you the idea of the page size.